# How does Facebook pre-empt URL extensions it needs in future?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I've been reading a lot recently on building community based applications, and when it comes to giving your user accounts 'cleaner' URL strucures, most are of the opinion that the user accounts should have a structure such as `example.com/user/username` rather than `example.com/username` which makes a lot of sense with regards to how mod-rewrite will handle the URL and serve the correct page with minimum potential problems. This ofcourse also helps in planning/ organizing file structure on website and future-proofing needs such as when later you will have your `example.com/blog`, which will not be taken by an existing user.

But the user-experience designer in me still wants to have the `example.com/username`. I'm just wondering, how did Facebook, Twitter and such applications pre-empt and reserve the URL names they would need, assuming that they did, so that they don't have issues with these years later, like today?

Did they pre-empt and reserve to themselves these extensions? Were they just lucky? It beats me.

Comment: _“But the user-experience designer in me still wants to have the `example.com/username`”_ – then “he” might be wrong, or is not actually thinking about user experience. With URLs such as `/user/foo` and `/blog/something`, users can directly tell from looking at the URL alone, that one will be a user profile, and the other a blog entry – removing that possibility, and then calling that a “better” user experience, makes little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook have a list of restricted usernames that are reserved for future projects. You can see this from a message when you attempt to take a reserved username. (Please choose another username.). Facebook also generate usernames from users' display names automatically so they rely on the fact that not many people try to change their username.

However, you could include in the TOS that usernames can change without notice. This means you can change a username (Maybe add an underscore to the end.) if you need the url.

Some sites do put a prefix url before the users accounts. This is useful if you want to redirect all user requests to another file. Sites like, (Planetminecraft.com/member/) and others use common urls like; member, user, account, username, profile, ect..

I suggest you pick whats best for you. It seems easier to put the username with a prefix url on the developing side, however some users/owners like people having a short url to their profile.

Comment: So you think in the early days they probably sat down and brainstormed on hundreds of names they wanted to reserve?

Including username change without notice in the TOS sounds like a good backup plan too.

Comment: I don't think they did when they started, however I believe they have now. Facebook don't have a problem with reserving names because they have already been reserved for them. All of the short usernames are taken by old accounts. Facebook have said inactive accounts can be modified and deleted as they please. So they just take the url they want form an old inactive account. I also believe they offer an extra name change to people who have urls they want, as Facebook do restrict each account to one name change.

Comment: @syedsuleman I'm saying simple ones like Facebook have reserved https://www.facebook.com/admin.

Comment: Makes sense. The best approach would be to reserve all the names one can possibly think one would need, then give oneself room to use/ take a specific URL if very necessary, and cover all this in the TOS.

Thanks dude!

Comment: @Eujomnoma You can also give usernames a prefix in the url, e.g. /@username that way you can still use any without the @

Comment: @Eujomnoma yes, that wold allow for you to keep all of the pages links available. Remember to save some usernames aswell, like @ anonymous, @ unknown; and @ deleted. These can come in handy if you want to keep content that belongs to deleted accounts, or to redirect a link of a deleted user.